# Resource planning within large project

Tags: resource-planning, templates

I am in the middle of a project that consists of 2 different teams, one team does migration of websites while the other team does development of features.

My challenge is to maintain an overview of which ressources are allocated to which features at any time given.

Some of the features require 1 developer while others require 2-3 developers at the same time.

I am trying to get a spread sheet together where I can see what developer is allocated to what feature in order to plan when the next feature should be planned for development.

Any good templates out there, MS excel or Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using excel for managing tasks as it's not easily maintained, customized and developers don't find it user friendly most of the time (if they are going to use it to track their tasks).

I recommend using a tool to plan the whole thing (project road map, milestones and  resource allocation).There are many tools that offer plan/see team workload feature like wrike,JIRA and droptask for an example.

You'd want to start with something as simple as wrike,then take it from there.

Comment: how would you do this in Jira? what plugins are needed?

Comment: I used to use the User load report https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/User+Workload+Report

But there are external plug-ins like desier, but I didn't try it personally. http://www.deiser.com/workload

Comment: Yassmeen I use Jira for task management and know the reports, but the problem is, I don't see away to plan ahead, only report on current resource situation

Comment: Found the feature in jira